# Android ExpandableListView populated twice

Tags: java, android, json, expandablelistview

I am using an expandable list view to display options and sub options respectively in a menu. The data coming in is correct, but oddly the listview seems to call the getChild and getChildView twice for each data entry and thus it is added to the view twice. It iterates through and then seems to iterate through again.

Example:

Categories:
 -Toys
 -Electronics
 -Cars
 -Toys
 -Electronics
 -Cars

Expected:
Categories:
 -Toys
 -Electronics
 -Cars

I am really new to Android and Java so I am probably making a rookie mistake. I have stepped through to try and find a point where it would be duplicating the data, but all I could find is that getChild/getChildView is being called twice.

Here is the expandableListView adapter class:

```
    public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> filterHeaderList;
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<JSONObject>> filterOptionsMap;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> filterHeaders, HashMap<String, ArrayList<JSONObject>> filterChildListMap) {
        this.context = context;
        this.filterHeaderList = filterHeaders;
        this.filterOptionsMap = filterChildListMap;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        JSONObject childObject = this.filterOptionsMap.get(this.filterHeaderList.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosititon);
        if (childObject != null) {
            Iterator<?> it = childObject.keys();
            String key = null;
            String value = null;
            if (it.hasNext()) {
                key = it.next().toString();
                try {
                    value = childObject.getString(key);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String[] data = new String[2];
                data[0] = key;
                data[1] = value;
                return data;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String childNum = null;
        String childText = null;
        final String[] childData = (String[]) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (childData != null) {
            childNum = childData[0];
            childText = childData[1];
        }
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.ps_filter_sort_filter_expandable_child, null);
        }

        TextView tvChildTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ps_filter_sort_filter_expandable_child_title);

        tvChildTitle.setText(childText);
        tvChildTitle.setTag(R.id.ps_filter_sort_filter_expandable_child_title + groupPosition + childPosition, childNum);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this.filterOptionsMap.get(this.filterHeaderList.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this.filterHeaderList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.filterHeaderList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.ps_filter_sort_filter_expandable_parent, null);
        }

        TextView tvGroupTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ps_filter_sort_filter_expandable_parent_title);
        tvGroupTitle.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        tvGroupTitle.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I then call it like this:

```
filterListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this.getActivity(), filterHeaderList, filterOptionsMap);
        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(filterListAdapter);
        filterListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

There are reasons the data is organized in this fashion which I'd rather not get into. What I can say is that the HashMap "filterOptionsMap" is correct and there is no duplication in it or the "filterHeaderList"

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have not been able to find someone having a similar issue and I've been banging my head on the keyboard over this.

Thank you.

**P.S.
You also need to tap the group heading twice to get it to collapse, but once to open. I don't know if it is related or expected behavior, but I would hope to have it be a single tap to toggle it open or closed. Bonus points for help with that as well.**

As requested here is some additional code related to the HashMap:

```
private void prepareFilterListData(ArrayList<String> headerList, JSONObject[] categoryList, JSONObject[] sellerList, JSONObject[] typeList) {
    filterHeaderArrayList = headerList;
    filterOptionsMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<JSONObject>>();

    // Adding child data
    ArrayList<JSONObject> categories = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    if (categoryList != null && categoryList.length > 0) {
        for (JSONObject category : categoryList) {
            categories.add(category);
        }
    }

    ArrayList<JSONObject> sellers = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    if (sellerList != null && sellerList.length > 0) {
        for (JSONObject seller : sellerList) {
            sellers.add(seller);
        }
    }

    ArrayList<JSONObject> types = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    if (typeList != null && typeList.length > 0) {
        for (JSONObject type : typeList) {
            types.add(type);
        }
    }

    filterOptionsMap.put(filterHeaderArrayList.get(0), categories);
    filterOptionsMap.put(filterHeaderArrayList.get(1), sellers);
    filterOptionsMap.put(filterHeaderArrayList.get(2), types);
}


    filterHeaderList = Directory.getFilterOptions();
    filterCategoryList = Directory.getFilterCategories();
    filterSellerList = Directory.getFilterSellers();
    filterTypeList = Directory.getFilterTypes();

    // Forms data structures from given input
    if (filterHeaderList != null && filterCategoryList != null && filterSellerList != null && filterTypeList != null) {
        prepareFilterListData(filterHeaderList, filterCategoryList, filterSellerList, filterTypeList);


private JSONObject[] getFilterTypes(JSONObject productSearchSettings, String filterTypes) {
    JSONArray typesObj;
    JSONObject[] types;
    try {
        typesObj = productSearchSettings.optJSONArray(filterTypes);
        if (typesObj != null) {
            types = new JSONObject[typesObj.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < typesObj.length(); i++) {
                String key = "type" + String.valueOf(i);
                String val = (String) typesObj.get(i).toString();
                types[i] = new JSONObject().put(key, val);
            }
            return types;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private JSONObject[] getFilterSellers(JSONObject productSearchSettings, String filterSellers) {
    JSONObject sellersObj = null;
    JSONObject[] sellers;
    try {
        sellersObj = productSearchSettings.getJSONObject(filterSellers);
        if (sellersObj != null) {
            sellers = new JSONObject[sellersObj.length()];
            Iterator<?> it = sellersObj.keys();
            int i = 0;
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String key = (String) String.valueOf(it.next().toString());
                String val = sellersObj.getString(key);
                sellers[i] = new JSONObject().put(key, val);
                i++;
            }
            return sellers;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private JSONObject[] getFilterCategories(JSONObject productSearchSettings, String filterCategories) {
    JSONObject categoriesObj = null;
    JSONObject[] categories;
    try {
        categoriesObj = productSearchSettings.getJSONObject(filterCategories);
        if (categoriesObj != null) {
            categories = new JSONObject[categoriesObj.length()];
            Iterator<?> it = categoriesObj.keys();
            int i = 0;
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String key = (String) String.valueOf(it.next().toString());
                String val = categoriesObj.getString(key);
                categories[i] = new JSONObject().put(key, val);
                i++;
            }
            return categories;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

As mentioned before, however the hashmap going into the adapter is correct. I verified through debugging.

Comment: Your data organization choice is normal for an `ExpandableListAdapter`. Seeing multiple invocations for `getChildView` and `getGroupView` is expected behavior. Adding twice is not though. Nothing seems to stand out with your adapter implementation. Can you post more code? Basically any portion of code that either interacts with the adapter or the data used to construct the adapter. Also include the methods they are in.

Comment: I have added additional code. It may also be worth noting that I am attempting to use a custom view for both the group and child views, but I don't think there is anything in those that could lead to duplication.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found it. I really appreciate the feedback and your help.

In the click event for the group, I was not returning true to indicate the click was handled. I was using the click event to toggle the expansion.

I don't know why exactly that would cause duplication and also require two clicks to close the group but toggling that return for the click event on the group made all the difference.

Comment: No wait, I up voted, then created a setOnGroupClickListener returning true but still getChildView is always called twice. Could you please explain better how you fixed it ?

Comment: You need to ensure that all click handlers related to the view are handled. Also, getChildView() is often called repeatedly as the view scrolls and what not. There is no avoiding that. The issue I had is that the views were actually populated twice. getChildView() was called twice, but instead of replacing a single child the next time it was called, it would actually create a new child. I would have double the children than normal. Is that the same issue you are having?

Comment: My issue is that every time I click a group, debugging, I see that getGroupView is called twice for all the visible groups and getChildView twice for the expanded one.
My problem is that I have a complex list where all the groups are of different types; one contains a picture, another 3 buttons, a seekbar, etc...
So getChildView sets the picture twice every time and this is not good.
Yesterday I've "fixed it" allowing only one expanded group per time. If I click a group, I collapse all the others.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure that the lack of `"return true"` could be the reason in your system, but since it didn't work for me, I add an answer as I've found a cause:

[ExpandableListView doc:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

> **Note**: You cannot use the value wrap_content for the
>   android:layout_height attribute of a ExpandableListView in XML if the
>   parent's size is also not strictly specified (for example, if the
>   parent were ScrollView you could not specify wrap_content since it
>   also can be any length. However, you can use wrap_content if the
>   ExpandableListView parent has a specific size, such as 100 pixels.

My ExpandableListView was in fact inside a LinearLayout with `height="wrap_content"`. Set it to `match_parent` and, voila, problem solved.

I'm not 100% sure but it could be that, with undefined height, the getChildView is called twice because of the re-sizing of the parent.

And it could be (I know it for personal experience, changing several parameters during testing is usually not a good idea as it creates misunderstandings on the causes) that you also set the height to `match_parent` while you added a `return true` and thought that the solution was the latter.

It would be helpful for all if you could just unset the height of the container of your ExpandableListView OR set the return to `false`and see which is the real cause. If both, well, we've found 2 causes.

Comment: Good insight. Thank you.

Comment: Hey I know this was not really what you had in mind but it helped me with checkBoxes in my Group (header). Android was creating new References (and made a new ViewHolder) so I never was able to find out where I checked the CheckBox. Changing the Layout to match_parent fixed this (still not sure why). Anyway, thank you so much!

Comment: Thankyou so much buddy 
Your answer helped me a lot 
I was stucked because of this issue

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm...Sorry to say, I'm still not seeing anything to cause that behavior.  Generally this could be caused by unknowingly adding new content. Usually because one modifies the data externally from the adapter.

In your case `filterHeaderList` in the adapter and the list returned by `Directory.getFilterOptions()` are the same list.  So if you modify that `Directory.getFilterOptions()` list, then you'll also inadvertently modify the adapter. Of course that method could just be generating a new list on the fly, so this may not even be a concern for you.

If you are positive the `filterHeaderList` is correct during the getChildView and getGroupView invocations, I'm not sure what else could be wrong. The custom group/child views would not cause this.

All I can suggest is resorting to some more aggressive debugging measures.  Basically start stripping that Activity/Fragment down to the bare bones.  Eliminate as many variables as possible so that you are just doing the most simplest case...loading an ExpandableListView and adapter with some data.

You could also try feeding in some fake data. Just try one child item with one group to see if it's still doubling everything.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I would up vote it because it is good advice but I want to make sure that if anyone else has this problem they can see the answer right away.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me: inside onGroupClick, remove call to parent.expandGroup(groupPosition), and make it return false;

```
expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            parent.expandGroup(groupPosition); // delete this
            Log.d(TAG, "onGroupClick: ");
            return false;
        }
    });
```